# How to use closures in a for loop in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of buttons in swift. Each button has a closure. I'm trying to use i in the for loop as a value in each closure.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            chapterOnePanel.chapters[i].onClickListener = {
                (x:Float32, y:Float32) in
                let r = i + 1;
                self.ChapterLoad = "1";
                self.LevelLoad = String(r);
                self.loadLevel = true;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I'm using **i** in the loop to store **i+1** in **r** and then store **r** in the **LevelLoad** variable. This doesn't work however, app crashes and LevelLoad is marked as nil. I know in Java you have to declare the **r** variable as final for it to work. Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Here is the answer as provided by GoZoner below.

```
     for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
              let r = i + 1;                    
              chapterOnePanel.chapters[i].onClickListener = {
                        (x:Float32, y:Float32) in

                        self.ChapterLoad = "1";
                        self.LevelLoad = String(r);
                        self.loadLevel = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" is meaningless flapdoodle. App crashes when? On what line? With what message?

Comment: As in the variable is marked as nil

Comment: Though to answer the one bit that's clearly a question: no. There's no such thing as final in Swift. Anonymous classes, ala Java, are very different from real closures.

Comment: @NJGUY Which variable is `nil`? Have you instantiated it yet? For example, did you instantiate the object that `chapterOnePanel` references? Assuming you did that, did you already instantiate the array of `chapters`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug:

```
var data : [(Int) -> ()] = []

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  data.append { (j:Int) in
    println (j + i)
  }
}

 9> data[0](10)  
15 // should be 10
```

*[Edit: Not actually a bug; this is the way some languages are, Swift too.  My described 'work around' is how you handle this (not just a 'work around')]*

The variable `i` IS NOT modified in the body of the closure, it thus MUST BE 'copied' (see '[Capturing Values](http://apple.co/1wKxBSi)') when the closure is created.  Instead, apparently, the compiler sees that `i` is modfiable, albeit outside of the closure, and incorrectly concludes that a 'reference' is needed.

To work around, move reference to the incorrectly captured `i`, outside of the closure:

```
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1> var data : [(Int) -> ()] = [] 
  2.  
  3. for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  4.   let r = i
  5.   data.append { (j:Int) in 
  6.     println (j + r)
  7.   } 
  8. } 
data: [Int -> ()] = 5 values {
  [0] = ($__lldb_expr2`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.Int) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in Swift.Int) -> (@out ()) at repl1.swift)
  ...
  [4] = ($__lldb_expr2`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.Int) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in Swift.Int) -> (@out ()) at repl1.swift)
}
  9> data[0](10)
10
 10> data[4](10)
14
```

Comment: I've seen the same behavior you describe, posted an answer to that effect, only to notice that when I tried it with the OP's code, it was copying it fine in this case (so I deleted my answer as it does not appear to be the problem in this situation). Also, the OP now reference some problem re a `nil` variable, which makes me think that there's a far simpler problem at play here, namely that he may have simply failed to initialize either `chapterOnePanel` or `chapters` (or something like that).