# Asynchronous calls in loop not working properly

Tags: swift, http, asynchronous, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire framework to handle HTTP requests.

I've got an array of feeds, and I need to loop through them and make a GET request for every feed.

```
    func getProfileImages(){


    var i = 0

    for feed in jsonFeeds {


        i++

        let author = feed.objectForKey("author") as! String


        Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/" + author +  "/image", headers: headers)
            .response { request, response, JSON, error in

                println("Profile Image request response:\(response)")
                println("Profile Image error:\(error)")


                if let dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSON!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {

                    self.imageUrls[i-1] = dict["url"] as? String
                    println(self.imageUrls)

                    if i == self.jsonFeeds.count {

                        println("count:\(self.jsonFeeds.count) , \(i)")

                        self.getCollabProfileImages()


                    }

                }
        }

    }
}
```

However, it looks like it's only doing the last Request, or something like that. 
In fact, println("count:(self.jsonFeeds.count) , (i)") always prints (count:6 , 6).

What is the problem here?

Comment: The  `i` variable is being shared by all your separate handlers in the loop, so its value is the last value in the loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891327/how-to-use-closures-in-a-for-loop-in-swift

Comment: @JuanMendes Alright I solved the issue. However, the imageUrls array is being populated randomly. For example, the first element has index 5, the second has index 1 and so on...