# Two loops on nested functions cause index to go beyond range

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, youtube-api

I have a function that calls Parse.com, returns an array of 10 ID's with a loop, and then for each one, it finds its data in youtube's API, also with a loop.

I am getting an error of 'index out of bounds' because for some reason, the index doesn't start over on the second loop, but carries on from when the first one left off. Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong?

```
func recomendedQuery(completion: (result: String)->()) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "VideosInfo")
    query.whereKeyExists("Rating")
    query.limit = 10
    query.orderByDescending("Rating")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for var i=0; i<10; i++ {
                let id = objects![i]["Video_ID"] as! String
                print(id) //No problems here
                self.recomQuery.append(id)
            }
            defaults.setObject(self.recomQuery, forKey: "recomQuery")
        } else {
            print(error?.description)
        }
    completion(result:"done")
    }
}

func getRecom(completion: (result:String)->()) {
    let array = defaults.arrayForKey("recomQuery")
    print(array![0])

    for var i=0; i<10; i++  {
    let videoURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2C+snippet&id=\(array![i])&maxResults=10&key=\(apiKey)"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, videoURL).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let videoTitle = json["items"][i]["snippet"]["title"].stringValue
                let thumbPath = String(json["items"][i]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"])
                print(videoTitle)
                print(thumbPath)
                print(i) //ERROR: PRINTS 10 AND ITS OUT OF BOUNDS
                let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: thumbPath)!)!)!
                let newImage: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
                self.recomTitles.append(videoTitle)
                self.recomThumbs.append(newImage)
                defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "gotRecom")
                completion(result: "done")
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(result: "done")
            }
        }
    }
defaults.setObject(recomThumbs, forKey: "recomThumbs")
defaults.setObject(recomTitles, forKey: "recomTitles")
}

    recomendedQuery { (result:String) -> () in //Call functions
        //CHANGE TO ONLY IF SUCCESS
            Networking().getRecom() { (result:String) -> () in
            self.recomView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to use a `for-in` loop so you won't get this problem. Next time try to narrow down your code and show only relevant information so it's easier for us to help you (most often you'll have found the problem by then too).

Comment: thanks! i tried that, but didnt work.. I also tried to marrow dowm my code. My problem is that I dont know where my problem is!

Comment: I've seen similar issues in JavaScript - basically creating a closure in a loop may not behave the way you think. The `i` will be captured by the closure, but if it is captured via reference, then the value of `i` can be mutated. See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891327/how-to-use-closures-in-a-for-loop-in-swift) for more details.

Comment: Here's a [more detailed article](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/19/swifts-for-loops-avoid-an-easy-mistake-with-variable-capture/) explaining why using a `for in` loop avoids this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This may help you.

```
func getRecom(completion: (result:String)->()) {

    let array = defaults.arrayForKey("recomQuery")
    print(array![0])

    for (index, object) in enumerate(array) {

        let videoURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2C+snippet&id=\(object)&maxResults=10&key=\(apiKey)"

        Alamofire.request(.GET, videoURL).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {

            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let videoTitle = json["items"][index]["snippet"]["title"].stringValue
                    let thumbPath = String(json["items"][index]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"])
                    print(videoTitle)
                    print(thumbPath)
                    print(index)
                    let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: thumbPath)!)!)!
                    let newImage: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
                    self.recomTitles.append(videoTitle)
                    self.recomThumbs.append(newImage)
                    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "gotRecom")
                    completion(result: "done")
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(result: "done")
            }
        }
    }

    defaults.setObject(recomThumbs, forKey: "recomThumbs")
    defaults.setObject(recomTitles, forKey: "recomTitles")
}

recomendedQuery { (result:String) -> () in //Call functions
//CHANGE TO ONLY IF SUCCESS
Networking().getRecom() { (result:String) -> () in
self.recomView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: what is participants? Im getting an 'undeclared' error.

Comment: My mistake, you have to use your array . Answer edited. Try now .Thanks